# FTP chown trigger after upload with symbolic links main www dir

Tags: ftp, upload, chmod, chown, proftpd

I'm using proftpd server with below dir structure:

main www dir:

```
/home/www
```

also there are some symbolic links to that main dir:

```
/home/john -> linked to /home/www
/home/mark -> linked to /home/www
```

etc.

When one of that users upload of new file he is the owner of that file but I need to change ownership and permissions for default 0755 and www:www
Of couse all users are in the same group www but sometimes user upload file with to low permissions so no one from group can change/remove the file from ftp.

Is there any way to do it automatically?

Comment: You might look into using ProFTPD's [`UserOwner`](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/modules/mod_core.html#UserOwner) and [`GroupOwner`](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/modules/mod_core.html#GroupOwner) directives.